# Position UIBarButtonItems with same offset from screen edges

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I've noticed that offset from edges for `UINavigationBar` left and right `UIBarButtonItems` is different for iPhone 5s/6s+. How would I supposed to have a fixed position from edges for all devices with different screen sizes?

I've tried `alignmentRectInsets` but that shift still is present...

Comment: Can you add screenshots for both iPhone 5s and 6s+ for the same?

Comment: Why do you want to.  iOS is setup like this for a reason.  If you change it for your app it will look out of place.